# Como usar o RxAndroid?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rxjava

estou tentando utilizar o RxAndroid mas não estou conseguindo compreender.

Na realidade, queria poder utilizar métodos dentro de uma Observable, para acessar o FirebaseFirestore e recuperar os dados para dentro do Realm.

Então a pergunta é: **Como faço para criar observables que retornam métodos?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela sua explicação e sua pergunta final vejo dois cenários. E sem ver o seu código só da pra fazer exemplos abstratos, então vamos lá.

### Primeiro cenário: Observables que trabalham com métodos

Para passar "métodos" no `Observable`, você vai ter que criar uma classe ou interface que declara esse método e usá-la. Da mesma forma que seria feito sem o Observable.

---

Exemplo com `Callable`:

```
// Type could be something else
Callable<String> callHello = new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // Could be a db query, api call... 
        return "Hello";
    }
};

Callable<String> callWorld = new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "World";
    }
};
```

O tipo do primeiro Observable seria `Callable<String>`, da seguinte forma:

```
Observable.just(callHello, callWorld)
        .map(new Function<Callable<String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Callable<String> callable) throws Exception {
                return callable.call();
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(String x) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        });
```

---

Um exemplo com um repositório de `Model`

Declaro o contrato:

```
interface ModelRepository<T extends Model> {
    List<T> listModels();
}
```

Tenho duas classes que obedecem este contrato.
Uma busca `User` (que extende `Model`):

```
class UserRepository implements ModelRepository<User> {

    @Override
    public List<User> listModels() {
        return userDAO.list();
    }
}
```

Outra busca `Event` (que também extende `Model`):

```
class EventRepository implements ModelRepository<Event> {

    @Override
    public List<Event> listModels() {
        return eventDAO.list();
    }
}
```

O Observable então começa com os repositórios e terminam com duas listas de `Model`

```
Observable.just(userRepository, eventRepository)
        .map(ModelRepository::listModels)
        .subscribe(listOfModels -> {/* do something with List<Model> */});
```

---

Nos dois casos estou passando um objeto que implementa um método declarado nas interfaces (`call` e `listModels`).

### Segundo cenário: Envolver APIs já existentes em Observables.

Para métodos bloqueantes a forma mais simples é utilizando o `fromCallable`:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> blockingGetUserFromRemote())
            .flatMap(user -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> blockingSaveUserToLocal(user)))
            .subscribe(saveResult -> { /* Do something with save result */ });
```

Neste caso tenho dois métodos bloqueantes: `blockingGetUserFromRemote` que busca um usuário num webservice e `blockingSaveUserToLocal` que salva o usuário no banco. Com o `fromCallable` é possível envolver eles em um `Callable` e utilizálos de forma não-bloqueante.

Para transformar listeners em Observables, recomendo ver o código fonte de alguma biblioteca que faz isso ([RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding), por exemplo). É um pouco mais complexo e longo.